Group by specific column value - Pandas
I have my dataframe set up like this



Cus_ID
Cus_Type
Cost
birthdate




123
Owner
50
01 Jan 1980


123
Spouse
50
10 Feb 1982


123
Father
300
01 Dec 1950


125
Owner
20
30 Jan 1990


125
Spouse
30
15 Jul 1994


125
Mother
100
06 Sep 1970



I am trying to do a groupby where I group by Cus_ID but return the cus_type owner such that the final product looks like this:



Cus_ID
Cus_Type
Cost
birthdate




123
Owner
400
01 Jan 1980


125
Owner
150
30 Jan 1990



I have a solution to work around it such as doing the groupby cus_id, summing the cost column then adding a column called cus_type on the new dataframe populated with cus_type then do a left join by cus_id and cus_type to the original DF to get the birth date.
Is there a better way to do it than the solution that I currently have?

I think a left-join can be fine, I provided a few alternatives below

Sort the rows to have the Owner first or last, then use a custom groupby.agg:
out = (df.sort_values(by='Cus_Type', key=lambda s: s.eq('Owner'))
         .groupby('Cus_ID', as_index=False)
         .agg({'Cus_Type': 'last', 'Cost': 'sum', 'birthdate': 'last'})
      )

Another way that is more generic if you have many columns:
d = dict.fromkeys(df.columns, 'last')
d['Cost'] = 'sum'

out = (df.sort_values(by='Cus_Type', key=lambda s: s.eq('Owner'))
         .groupby('Cus_ID', as_index=False).agg(d)
      )

# OR

out = (df.assign(flag=df['Cus_Type'].eq('Owner'))
         .groupby('Cus_ID', as_index=False)
         .agg({'flag': 'idxmax', 'Cost': 'sum'})
      )

out = out.join(df.drop(columns=['Cus_ID', 'Cost'])
                 .reindex(out.pop('flag')).reset_index(drop=True))

Output:
   Cus_ID Cus_Type  Cost    birthdate
0     123    Owner   400  01 Jan 1980
1     125    Owner   150  30 Jan 1990


mydict={"Owner":1}
df['num']=df['Cus_Type'].map(mydict)
df1=df.groupby(['Cus_ID']).agg({"Cus_Type":"first","Cost":"sum","birthdate":"first"}).reset_index()


This just works by chance, if you shuffle the rows in the input this would give an incorrect output. Also, the map step is not doing anything.
